# Несколько серверов для одного домена

Tags: apache, сервер, hosting

Как реализуется мультисерверная структура сайта? Допустим у меня есть домен, и мне надо что бы нагрузка на него распределялась на 2 и более сервера - как такое реализовывается?

Возможно есть хостинг где можно приобрести услугу где все это уже будет настроено и останется только при необходимости докупать дополнительные сервера?
Или это можно делать самому просто приобретая у хостера несколько серверов и виртуально соединяя их?

Comment: Самое простое решение в DNS у доменного имени несколько IP адресов указывающих разумеется на разные физические сервера. Либо на одном ip ставится мультиплексор-прокси которая по определенным правилам распределяет запросы по исполняющим серверам

Comment: У меня более серьезный вопрос в ответ - а с базой данных как будете поступать? Или там раздача только файлов?

Comment: @АлексейПрисяжный с БД как я понял самый хороший вариант это выделить чисто под нее один сервер, т.е. все запросы обрабатываются на n-ом количестве серверов, а БД на отельном к которому идут запросы от тех серверов. Если на каждом сервере делать свою БД то будет много проблем с синхронизацией.

Comment: Тут как раз всё начнёт упираться в производительность БД. Один из вариантов решения, в случае с mysql - master-slave синхронизация, при этом запись идёт только в головную, из слэйвов только чтение. Или вообще noSQL смотреть, там выбор разнообразный.

Answer (score 3):

на будущее - Apache в принципе излишний в большинстве задач, плюс кушает порядком памяти, nginx заменяет его отлично.

1. Использовать DNS-robin, просто в качестве A записей к домену добавляется перечень ип адресов серверов. Браузер случайным образом выбирает ип, нагрузка примерно поровну.
2. Лучше вариант - использовать nginx, модуль upstream.
   Архитектура будет такой - есть пачка настроенных серверов (с чем угодно),  к доменному имени привязан простейший сервер с достаточно толстым каналом, у которого крутится nginx с конфигом:

```
    upstream backend {
        server backend1.example.com       weight=5;
        server backend2.example.com:8080;
        server unix:/tmp/backend3;

        server backup1.example.com:8080   backup;
        server backup2.example.com:8080   backup;
    }

    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
        }
    }
```

обратите внимание, можно сослаться даже на unix socket, то есть один из серверов может быть прямо на сервере с балансировкой нагрузки.